# Why is "combine HSV" node showing different color with the same values?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color

I made a glass object and gave it a desired color, but now I want to animate its hue at the end of the animation (like and outro). So I used the "Combine HSV" node and used the exact same values to remake the color.

[image]

But here you can see when the color is remade in the HSV node using the same values, the HSV node is giving out a different color. (object preview on the left)

[image]

I have already decided on the first color and don't want to change it.
Why is this difference happening and how do I solve it.

Thankyou.

Comment: I am sorry this doesnt seem to solve the problem. I also dont understand how do I plug the value node to the inputs of the HSV node. That will just make it a bright red color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a gamma node with 2.2 in between combine and bsdf nodes. I tried it and it seems to work.

The one on the right uses the other glass bsdf
[image: The one on the right uses the other glass bsdf]

> I’d assume the RGB color picker is gamma corrected (to preserve the linear workflow), whereas the Combine HSV node as a - let’s say - more mathematical approach to color is not.
> Add a Gamma node with a value of 1/2.2 between the RGB node and the Emission shader and you will get the same values as with the Combine HSV node.

Source: https://blenderartists.org/t/different-outputs-of-rgb-and-combine-hsv/675268

Comment: Maybe this should be brought to devs just to make sure it's intended and not a bug. And if intended, maybe there could be some detailed information on the official manual.

Comment: This did help getting the same color, thankyou for that. I also wanted to know what if I wanted the hue value to go round the color wheel and loop back to the same color in an animation. Usually I only go from 0.000 to 1.000 and it makes a color loop. But now that we are at 0.066 how do I make it loop? (Not really important but maybe there is a solution)

Comment: @Bits168 One way to go about it would be to use a modulus operator with a modulus value of 1. Then only the fraction part of given value will be taken into account (like this https://i.imgur.com/OkWXue2.png. Here the cube on the right has a hue value of 0.066, while the one on the left has 100.066. Should work with any value). Perhaps there is a way to do it with animation curves, but I'm not too familiar with animation.

Comment: @L0Lock It IS rather unintuitive. Although the issue appears to have been brought to their attention some time ago: https://developer.blender.org/T52772

Comment: Thanks for the link. « *Maybe @Brecht Van Lommel (brecht) would love to revisit this at some rainy day tho* » made me laugh 